# Issue to delete a line in a FindNext loop

Tags: excel, vba

With this code I'm trying to search cells in a column where there is a comma character, and divide it into 2 new cells.

Next I want to **Delete** the original line, but it seems impossible as the value is used in **FindNext** operation.

**What I have :**

```
Column D       Column E
Carrot         Vegetable 
Apple,Banana   Fruit
```

**What I need :**

```
Column D       Column E
Carrot         Vegetable 
Apple          Fruit
Banana         Fruit
```

**What I've done :**

```
Sub newentry()
'
' newentry Macro
'

Dim line
Dim col
Dim content

With Sheets("Feuil3").Columns("D")
    Set c = .Find(",", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do

        c.Select
            line = ActiveCell.Row
            col = ActiveCell.Column
            content = ActiveCell
            category = Cells(line, "E")

            Dim Table() As String
            Dim i As Integer

            'split content in a table
            Table = Split(content, ",")

            'loop on table
            For i = 0 To UBound(Table)
            'copy result on next line
                Rows(line + 1).Insert
                Tableau(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Table(i))
                Cells(line + 1, col).Value = Table(i)
                Cells(line + 1, "E").Value = category


                Next i

                Set c = .FindNext(c)

                If c Is Nothing Then
                    GoTo DoneFinding
                End If
                 'where/how to do this ?
                 Rows(c.Row).Delete Shift:=xlUp         
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

        End If
DoneFinding:
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I delete the line that I just found ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have data in column **D** like:

[image]

Running this short macro:

```
Sub Restructure()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arr1, arr2, arr3, a1, s As String

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1
    arr1 = Range("D1:D" & N)

    For Each a1 In arr1
        s = Mid(a1, 2, Len(a1) - 2)
        If InStr(s, ",") = 0 Then
            Cells(j, "E").Value = "[" & s & "]"
            j = j + 1
        Else
            arr2 = Split(s, ",")
            For Each a2 In arr2
                Cells(j, "E").Value = "[" & a2 & "]"
                j = j + 1
            Next a2
        End If
    Next a1
End Sub
```

will produce this in column **E**:

[image]

NOTE:

The original data is not disturbed.

Comment: Hi, thank you. As I'm working on data base, I need the datas to be disturbed ;) 
I have other datas in column E, F.... that I'm also copying on the new lines.

Answer (score 1):

insert as many lines as needed minus one below the found cell,

then simply write needed data including found cell row

don't rely on any `ActiveCell`, just use the `c` range object you found

```
Sub newentry()
'
' newentry Macro
'

    Dim content As String, Category As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Table() As String

    With Sheets("Feuil3").Columns("D")
        Set c = .Find(",", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Do
                content = c
                Category = c.Offset(, 1).Value2

                'split content in a table
                Table = Split(content, ",")
                c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Resize(UBound(Table)).Insert ' insert as many rows needed minus one below the found cell
                c.Resize(UBound(Table) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Table) ' write contents in as many cells as needed, including the found one
                c.Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(Table) + 1).Value = Array(Category, Category) ' write category in as many cells as needed one column to the right of found one
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice solution.Rep added

Comment: Hi, Thank you. As my function will be applied on different datas, for now I just have the comma to use.

Comment: you are welcome. but I can't understand your comment: does my solution work for you?

Comment: @DisplayName, not really  (I've updated my question). I need to create new lines for every word (separeted by a comma), and next delete the old line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, b, x, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

a = Range("D1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a) * 3, 1 To UBound(a, 2))

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    If InStr(a(i, 1), ",") > 0 Then
        x = Split(a(i, 1), ",")
        For j = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
            k = k + 1
            b(k, 1) = Trim(x(j))
            b(k, 2) = a(i, 2)
        Next j
    Else
        k = k + 1
        b(k, 1) = a(i, 1)
        b(k, 2) = a(i, 2)
    End If
Next i

Columns("D:E").ClearContents
Range("D1").Resize(k, UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, as I'm not working only with these datas, I won't be able to use [ or ] characters